# Row count from one table, store value in another table

Tags: php, sql, pdo, rowcount

I need to count rows in one table, and store the value in another row by making use of PHP and SQL (PBO is most appreciated).

**I HAVE: TABLE NEWS**

```
TABLE NEWS (contains stories and the companies where the stories are about)
-----------------
|ID|newstitle|newscontent|company|date|
|1| TITLE EXAMPLE | This is a story | DELL,HP,APPLE | 27-03-2016|
|2| TITLE EXAMPLE | This is another story | APPLE,MICROSOFT,GOOGLE | 29-03-2016|
```

**I DESIRE: (PARTIALLY) TABLE COMPANY**

```
TABLE COMPANY (contains company name and how much a news item is mentioned about a company)
-----------------
|ID|company|articles|
|1| APPLE  | 2 |
|2| Dell  | 1|
```

What I need is a PHP script that can count how much each company is mentioned in TABLE NEWS, and store the value in the row of the company in TABLE COMPANY.

For example: There are two articles about Apple in *Table News*, which leads to the value 2 in column articles in *table company*. I hope someone can give me a hint!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and where you've failed?

Comment: I don't think this is the best approach to keep company names as comma separated. You must create one more table may be tags in which you keep id of news (i.e news_id) and company (i.e company_id). Than you can easily get count for any company as well as a given News related to which company or companies.